# phpmyadmin have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, debian-squeeze

I use debian 6.0.6, before I install phpmyadmin, I install this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install apache2 apache2-doc autoconf automake \
bison ca-certificates ethtool flex g++ gcc gcc-4.4 libapache2-modphp5 \
libcrypt-ssleay-perl libmysqlclient-dev libnet1 libnet1-dev libpcre3 \
libpcre3-dev libphp-adodb libssl-dev libtool libwww-perl make mysqlclient \
mysql-common mysql-server ntp php5-cli php5-gd php5-mysql php-pear \
sendmail sysstat vim
```

I try to install phpmyadmin, but I found this error:

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

And I tried this command:

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin php5-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-mcrypt : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-7+squeeze17) but 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

What should I do?

Comment: What have you done to your apt sources?

Comment: I want to install snort first, after that, I tried to install phpmyadmin to see my database easier.. here is my sources.list content:

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

Answer (score 1):

Your 'php5-common' appears to be provided by "Dotdeb" which is a third party site that distributes packages. Either you were messing with your sources.list previously and reverted the change, or you didn't post the complete list here. Or, a possible third option, you may have manually downloaded the .deb file from Dotdeb and installed it manually.

As a result of the non-Squeeze package, your packaging system is broken. You're trying to install (from the Squeeze repository, according to your sources.list) a package (php5-mcrypt) that depends on the php5-common that is also from Squeeze (version 5.3.3-7+squeeze17), but what you actually have is the Dotdeb version (5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0). Since the versions don't match, php5-mcrypt won't install.

Unless you have a good reason to want packages from non-Debian sources -- and know how to deal with conflicts when the occur -- I recommend sticking only with the official sources. First, make sure your sources.list doesn't mention Dotdeb and update aptitude or apt-get to make sure they're working off the updated list in cache. Then, just to be safe, back up the associated configuration files, remove the Dotdeb files (at least php5-common and probably anything it depends on), and re-install them. If you don't purge the package, the configuration file should stay, but that's assuming the Dotdeb people use the same locations (which is relatively likely, but I don't know anything about them so I won't promise it).